# How can i find the largest gameobject size from array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void Awake()
    {
        Clone();
        objects = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("ClonedObject");

        float size = objects[0].transform.localScale.x;
    }
```

The float size is just for a test.

Inside Clone() function i set the size for each gameobject

```
for (var i = 0; i < ObjectCount; i++)
        {
            var o = Instantiate(ObjectToCreate);
            o.tag = "ClonedObject";
            o.transform.SetParent(base.gameObject.transform);
            o.transform.localScale = new Vector3(ObjectSize, ObjectSize, ObjectSize);
```

The variable ObjectSize is global

I want in the Awake function to find the biggest size of a gameobject form all the gameobjects in the array. So float size will get the biggest gameobject size.
Then to find the gameobject radius so size/2 i think.

Then later i want to use the variable size in other script so i will make it global public and static. But first how do i find the biggest gameobject by size from the array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But first how do i find the biggest gameobject by size from the array
>   ?

inside your `Awake()` method you can simply use a for each loop to find the largest value.

```
float LargestSize = 0;
foreach(var element in objects){
  float Size = element.transform.localScale.x;
  if(Size > LargestSize) LargestSize = Size;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know much about unity, but the simplest way i could think of is ordering them by their size and take the first one:

```
var maxobj = objects.OrderByDescending(i => i.Size).FirstOrDefault();
```

if you just need the size use the following:

```
var maxsize = objects.Max(i => (int?)i.Size) ?? 0;
```